How can I get a connection with my bluetooth dongle on my pc and my smartphone to transfer audio via a2dp and avcrp?
I'm doing a study project where I'm supposed to write a Bluetooth integration into an infotainment system in WPF C#. The infotainment system runs on Windows 10.
I write a code in c# with 32feet.net and a bluetooth usb dongle for my connection.
If I try to connect my BluetoothClient named client with my BluetoothEndPoint it only gets a connection when I use BluetoothService.Handsfree or BluetoothService.SerialPort.
But if I use BluetoothService.AudioSink or some other BluetoothService possibilities the client can't connect.
Now the questions are: Does my bluetooth dongle not support a2dp and avrcp profile?
And if yes, how can I check the bluetooth profiles on my dongle?
I can't see any bluetooth dongles online that also have the bluetooth profiles shown.
Are there special pages to get them?
I tried different bluetooth usb dongles and the intern bluetooth from my notebook, but there is no connection if I try with a2dp and avrcp.

There is no way on Windows to connect to A2DP (or any other audio profile) on your smarphone. You can connect to headsets/headphones only. However you can not control it because there is no such Windows API (Windows provides API for RFCOMM connections only and does not provide any other, especially for SCO connections).
